# json explosion how do I process it in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, xml, sql-server-2017

I have a JSON as below:

```json
{
    "totalRecords": 1117,
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "ItemCode": "0000000000000P88",
            "ItemDescription": "SS-CRATES REC/RET",
            "HQCost": 5,
            "ingredients": "<explosion></explosion>"
        },
        {
            "ItemCode": "000000000ABC1006",
            "ItemDescription": "SNACK - wings",
            "HQCost": 10.3364,
            "ingredients": "<explosion><ingredient><code>0000000KMI050053</code><qty>1.000000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI053301</code><qty>1.000000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI053555</code><qty>0.022000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI056053</code><qty>2.000000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI061314</code><qty>0.030000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI061356</code><qty>0.026680</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI071104</code><qty>0.032000</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>0000000KMI071873</code><qty>0.000560</qty></ingredient><ingredient><code>000000KMI010021A</code><qty>4.000000</qty></ingredient></explosion>"
        }
    ]
}
```

The second ingredient:

```xml
<explosion>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI050053</code>
        <qty>1.000000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI053301</code>
        <qty>1.000000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI053555</code>
        <qty>0.022000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI056053</code>
        <qty>2.000000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI061314</code>
        <qty>0.030000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI061356</code>
        <qty>0.026680</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI071104</code>
        <qty>0.032000</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>0000000KMI071873</code>
        <qty>0.000560</qty>
    </ingredient>
    <ingredient>
        <code>000000KMI010021A</code>
        <qty>4.000000</qty>
    </ingredient>
</explosion>
```

I can read the JSON file but the ingredients part is an explosion which I am unsure of how to split apart into multiple columns against the product.

Currently I am using the following script in SQL to read the file.

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Temp\MenuItemListing.json', SINGLE_CLOB) import
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.data')
WITH  (
   [ItemCode] varchar(50),   
   [ItemDescription] varchar(100),  
   [HQCost] float,
   [ingredients] VARCHAR(MAX)
   );
```

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: What is your DBMS? [why should i tag my rdbms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Please also show the desired result. You can cast [ingredients] as `XML` and proceed with your DBMS' xml tools.

Comment: I am using SSMS

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the desired result is. Anyway cast [ingredients] as XML and parse it a way you want. For example

```
 SELECT t.[ItemCode], t. [ItemDescription], t.[HQCost] 
    , x.n.value('code[1]', 'varchar(50)') ing_code
    , x.n.value('qty[1]', 'decimal(10,7)') ing_val
 FROM OPENJSON (@JSON,'$.data') 
 WITH  (
    [ItemCode] varchar(50),   
    [ItemDescription] varchar(100),  
    [HQCost] float,
    [ingredients] XML
    ) t
 outer apply [ingredients].nodes('explosion/ingredient') x(n);
```

With your sample data the query returns

```
ItemCode    ItemDescription HQCost  ing_code    ing_val
0000000000000P88    SS-CRATES REC/RET   5       
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI050053    1.0000000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI053301    1.0000000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI053555    0.0220000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI056053    2.0000000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI061314    0.0300000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI061356    0.0266800
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI071104    0.0320000
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 0000000KMI071873    0.0005600
000000000ABC1006    SNACK - wings   10.3364 000000KMI010021A    4.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My desired result would be to take the items that doesn't contain anything in explosion and write that to a master file and the items that do contain explosions, write them to child file linking the products with the ingredients required to make the product.

Again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @user2361958 Foer the first part of that you can use `WHERE t.ingredients].exist('explosion/ingredient') = 0` and for the second part switch `OUTER APPLY ingredients.nodes` to `CROSS APPLY ingredients.nodes`